# Perl: exec() on Windows vs. Unix

Tags: perl, exec

Below code works as I would expect on Unix - system() call blocks until child process finishes.
On Windows though it works differently - system() blocks only till child script reaches exec(), then it returns immediately, and exec-ed child script continues to run in background. Is there a way to make it work the same way as on Unix?

```
# main script
my $myCmd = [$^X, 'myScript.pl', 'arg1', 'arg2'];
system($^X, 'runcmd.pl', @$myCmd);


# runcmd.pl
open(STDOUT, '>', 'out.tmp');
open(STDERR, '>', 'err.tmp');
my $exe = shift @ARGV;
unless(exec($exe, @ARGV))
{
    close(STDOUT);
    close(STDERR);
    exit(1);
}

# myScript.pl - any script that runs few seconds and produces some output, e.g:
foreach (1..5)
{
    sleep 1;
    print "$_\n";
}
```

Comment: Win32 doesn't really have an equivalent to `exec` syscalls so I wouldn't be surprised if its emulation has different semantics. `perlport` does have some warnings about it.

Comment: @Shawn Indeed, but this is all by the docs.  Even the dedicated [perlfork](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfork.html) clearly states in a few places  that "pseudo processes" are waited for.  I'm puzzled.  (Can't play with it on Windows right now...)

Comment: @zdim He's not using `fork` though.

Comment: @Shawn Right, but the docs seem to relate to all of it.  And here the thing is with the `system`, which doesn't wait (so `fork`).  It just seems _from the docs_ that it "should"

Comment: @zdim Looking at the source, `exec` on Windows follows different paths depending on if it's using one of those fork psuedo-processes or not. The fast non-fork path calls `_execvp()` (I was wrong about Windows not having an equivalent), which sounds like it just calls `CreateProcess()` and exits.

Comment: @Shawn Ah, interesting.  That then highlights the main question, of why does the initial `system` not wait?  Since the `exec` did (in one way or another) turn into something else, then what makes the `system` (which started it all) exit?

Comment: @zdim I suspect that what happens is that the `system` call does wait until the child process ends; it's just that the child process is only around very briefly before starting a grandchild process the original one running `system` doesn't know about and then exiting.

Comment: @Shawn Seems like that, since here we get a _new_ process with "exec", unlike with Unix `exec`, the original `system` looses track of it.  The docs never let us in on that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not exactly, no. Simply put, `exec` changes the program being executed by the current process. This is not something supported by Windows.

Perl apparently emulates `exec` by executing the program in a new process and exiting the existing process. Like on unix systems, this leaves a single program running.

You could get the desired result on Windows by replacing `exec` with `system`.

Alternatively, avoid the second program entirely. [IPC::Run](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Run) and [IPC::Run3](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Run3) are solid modules for launching other programs.

```
use IPC::Run qw( run );

run [ $^X, 'myScript.pl', 'arg1', 'arg2' ],
   '>', "out.tmp",
   '2>', "err.tmp";
```

Even low-level but core [IPC::Open3](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Open3) would work here.

```
use IPC::Run qw( open3 );

open(local *CHILD_STDOUT, '>', 'out.tmp') or die $!;
open(local *CHILD_STDERR, '>', 'err.tmp') or die $!;

my $pid = open3('<&STDIN', '>&CHILD_STDOUT', '>&CHILD_STDERR',
   $^X, 'myScript.pl', 'arg1', 'arg2');

waitpid($pid, 0);
```

Comment: You are right! I thought exec would result in myScript.pl running with the same PID as runcmd.pl, which I now can see is not true. I am already using the solution with open3, but unfortunately it does not work well when external programs are called from concurrent Perl threads. I am actually trying to find an alternative.

Comment: The Windows system call to create processes, `CreateProcess`, accepts file handles for STD*. This would do the trick. Unfortunately, Win32::Process doesn't expose that functionality. Maybe there's another module. Or you could use Win32::API, I suppose, but that's pretty advanced.